# How can I determine which file filter was matched for a FileSystemWatcher event?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, filesystemwatcher, filepattern

I am using a `FileSystemWatcher` as follows:

```csharp
using watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\path\to\folder");

watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                     | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                     | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                     | NotifyFilters.FileName
                     | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                     | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                     | NotifyFilters.Security
                     | NotifyFilters.Size;

watcher.Created += OnCreated;
watcher.Error += OnError;

foreach(string filter in filters) 
{
    watcher.Filters.Add(filter);
}

watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

The `OnCreated` event handler is defined as follows:

```csharp
private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string value = $"Created: {e.FullPath}";
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Now, I want to know if is there a way I can find from exactly which filter specified in the `Filters` list has the event been raised?

For example,

1. I am watching `C:\FileWatcherDemo` with the `OnCreated` event handler.
2. `"f1_\*.txt"` and `"f2_\*.txt"` are added to `Filters`.
3. I add `"f1_demo.txt"` to the folder.
4. I have the `sender` object and the `FileSystemEventArgs` passed as argument to my `OnCreated` handler.

How can I know that the `OnCreated` event was actually matched by the `"f1_*.txt"` filter?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you need, I think you will only be able to know the filter triggered by validating against the name of the file that arrives in "OnCreated".

Comment: FSW does not actually have that feature natively, it got added in .NETCore by watching for `"*.*"` and checking the filename against the list before firing the event.  The code is that does that check is [readily available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumeration.filesystemname.matchessimpleexpression?view=net-6.0#system-io-enumeration-filesystemname-matchessimpleexpression(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-boolean)), just call it yourself.

Comment: Thanks  @HansPassant, I can work around with the file watcher now.

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IObservable<(NotifyFilters NotifyFilter, FileSystemEventArgs FileSystemEventArgs)> query =
    from nf in new []
    {
        NotifyFilters.Attributes,
        NotifyFilters.CreationTime,
        NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
        NotifyFilters.FileName,
        NotifyFilters.LastAccess,
        NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
        NotifyFilters.Security,
        NotifyFilters.Size,
    }.ToObservable()
    from u in Observable.Using(
        () => new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\path\to\folder"),
        fsw => Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(h => fsw.Created += h, h => fsw.Created -= h))
    select (nf, u.EventArgs);
    

IDisposable subscription =
    query.Subscribe(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Created: {x.FileSystemEventArgs.FullPath}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Created: {x.NotifyFilter}");
    });
```

It effectively creates separate `FileSystemWatcher` instances for each filter yet produces a single merged stream of events preserving the `NotifyFilter` used.